# How can I implement Active Directory in my ASP.Net Core 2.0 project?

Tags: asp.net, angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a web application that uses Angular and an ASP.NET Core back-end. My plan is, when the user goes onto the site, they are authenticated right away. And depending on what group their in they can access certain features on the site.

I have tried this https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/0b6803b6-c5c4-445b-9ece-575849a98474/get-users-distribution-groups?forum=ITCG but it doesn't work as it used PowerShell. If anyone can point me in the right direction or show an example that would be appreciated.

Comment: Probably nothing - if the browser and server machine belong to the same domain they'll perform the NTLM authentication flow automatically, or the *browser* will ask for credentials. What you linked to has nothing to do with authentication. It's about *email distribution groups*

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It is an in home app, so the server will be under the same domain. I would like to get the groups from email distribution groups.

Comment: What do you mean by AD in the first place? Domain authentication where browsers and servers in the same or trusted domains recognize each other? That's configured out of the box when you create a new ASP.NET Core project with Windows Authentication. Or using form authentication and looking up the user/password  in an AD or LDAP server?

Comment: Then you really don't have to do anything. Just select Windows Authentication in the dialog box. Email groups are *not* the same as domain groups and shouldn't be used. They are distribution lists for email. If you want to *authorize* users based on their group membership, you should use Windows or Domain groups

Comment: Yes, both browsers and servers are in the same domain. I have checked my windows authentication check box. Would I need the user to type in there username and password? And not just get authenticated just by their user name?

Comment: You shouldn't have to do anything. Did you *try* it? Just create a new project with Windows authentication and *run* it. If the *browser* is configured for automatic login it won't even ask for credentials. Otherwise it will ask but *not* send them to the server. It will create the appropriate tokens locally

Comment: Even during debugging the server will ask you, the developer, to authenticate. If you use Fiddler you can see that the browser will try with an anonymous call, the server will return a 401 with a Challenge header and the browser will respond back with an Authentication header. Each request will result in new authentication headers to prevent replay attacks. No credentials are ever exchanged between the browser and server

Comment: The user was authenticated but how would I get his/her's groups and first name and etc...

Comment: You are asking about a tutorial on Windows authentication now. You don't *need* to get the name, you already have it through the account. You can access it through the `User.Identity` class. I think the default template has a `Hello @(User.Identity.Name)` snippet in the toolbar. For *authorization* you don't need to know the groups, you specify the group that's authorized to perform an action through an attribute, a config setting or use the `User.IsInRole()` method.

Comment: That and a lot more is provided by the ASP.NET Identity system which *abstracts* the actual provider and returns the same API for all. I insist on separating authentication (you are who you say you are) from authorization (you are allowed to execute that action) because they are treated differently and in fact, you could have different providers. Eg use Windows Auth for authentication but your own roles stored in a database.

Comment: Getting eg emails, departments etc for a user is his/her *Profile*. ASP.NET Identity provides an abstraction for that as well. Check [Introduction to Identity on ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio%2Caspnetcore2x)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It worked in .net mvc but not in netcore. I get Hello, ! not Hello, DOMAIN/USERNAME!   Can we private message?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you might have noticed is that the System.DirectoryServices namespace is not available in .Net Core. Because .Net Core is cross-platform the app has no idea in what environment it is running in, it can be on a Linux server where there is no Active Directory, so implementing System.DirectoryServices in the .Net Core framework makes no sense.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Novell.Directory.Ldap.NETStandard/

1) Install the Novell library
We begin by installing the Novell.Directory.Ldap.NETStandard package:

`PM> Install-Package Novell.Directory.Ldap.NETStandard -Version 2.3.8`

Comment: This answer is partially correct. On Windows, developers can use Windows Compatibility Pack https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/11/16/announcing-the-windows-compatibility-pack-for-net-core/